# l10n.js button doesn't reload page

Tags: javascript, html, localization, l10n.js

I'm building a multilanguage site and i am using the l10n.js library, the example doesn't come with links to refresh the language on user's choice, so i create 2 buttons but they only work if the user refresh the page manually, it only works the first time you click, then you gotta click again and refresh manually...

I'm not a java expert but i can understand the logic, so i tried with different window.location.href but none of them seems to work. here is the fiddle if somebody can take a look, thanks.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud1o0ddk/)

```
ud1o0ddk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now, i did add `window.location.reload(true)`, I will leave it there just in case somebody else need it.